# React - Date-fns get timezone

Tags: javascript, reactjs, date-fns

`parse('11.02.87', 'd.MM.yy', new Date()).toString()`

with this code it get this result : `WED FEB 11 1987 00:00:00 GMT+0700 (WIB)`

on Date-FNS how to get `(WIB)` format?

I've tried using timezone still no luck

`format(utcToZonedTime(parseISO(data.timestamp), tz), 'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss \'GMT\' XXX (z)', { timeZone: 'Asia/Jakarta' })}`

on moment-timezone I can use `z` as format to get (WIB) result

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to format using formatToTimeZone, like described here: https://date-fns.org/v2.0.0-alpha.27/docs/Time-Zones

```
formatToTimeZone(date, format, { timeZone: 'Asia' })
```

For timezones codes: https://www.timeanddate.com/time/zones/

Comment: i'm not using alpha version. i think on latest version formatToTimezone is no longer exists